# vue-query return ObjectRefImpl and not the data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, fetch-api, vue-composition-api

vuejs community I'm a newbie on vue.js, to fetch data with vue-query, vue.js 3, and composition API, the returned data is ObjectRefImpl.
When I print the values It returns me: Property "isLoading" was accessed during render but is not defined on the instance.
So much thanks!

"vue": "^3.2.12",
"vue-query": "^1.11.0"

Todo.vue

```js
import {onMounted} from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const fetcher = async () => {
      await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(response =>
        response.json()
      );
    };

    onMounted(() => {
      const {data, isError, error, isLoading} = useQuery('todos', fetcher);
      console.log(data);
      return {isLoading, isError, data, error};
    });
  }
};
```

App.vue

```js
<script>
import {defineComponent} from 'vue';
import {useQueryProvider} from 'vue-query';
import {VueQueryDevTools} from 'vue-query/devtools';

export default defineComponent({
  components: {VueQueryDevTools},
  name: 'App',
  setup() {
    useQueryProvider();
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <VueQueryDevTools :initialIsOpen="true" />
  <router-view />
</template>
```

main.js

```js
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';


import './index.scss';

createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make it work if you modify your component a little bit.

```
const fetcher = async () => {
    await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(response =>
      response.json()
    );
  };

export default {
  setup() {
    const {data, isError, error, isLoading} = useQuery('todos', fetcher);
    console.log(data.value);
    return {isLoading, isError, data, error};
  }
};
```

All values returned by vue-query are refs, so you have to access them by accessing `.value`. This is due to Vue reactivity system, and it is necessary, so you can get automatic updates on those values.

Also you need to place your `useQuery` calls directly in `setup`. They will run and update whenever necessary without any action from your side.

You have a working example for this following this link: https://github.com/DamianOsipiuk/vue-query/tree/main/examples/simple